# Change the style of matched words on Google search page results

Tags: google-chrome, themes

When using a light theme on the browser, the matched words appear bold black, as in screenshot 1
[light theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MHG5.png)

But when using the dark theme (my favorite), it also appears bold, it is not very clear as in screenshot 2
[dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csEJf.png)
So how to change the matched words format on google page search results on dark theme, to bold yellow an example?
Thanks